# How to export the remote MySQL database to local SQL file using python script?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to export all databases from Wordpress and save it in local file as .sql format. Is there any ways to achieve this with native python code (no mysqldump)? Please help me.

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(host,user,passwd, port, db)

# method for downloading io from Wordpress

with open('local.sql', 'w') as local_sql:
     # write io to local.sql
```

Comment: why not mysqldump?

Comment: Not sure why you want to replicate mysqldump's functionality....